# Reading columns from .txt file in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find the minimum value from a table. How do you find the minimum value from multiple columns in a `.txt` file

```
TheTable = importdata('myfile.txt')
TheYear = TheTable(:,1);
ColumnsWithValues = TheTable(2:13);
MininumValue = min(TheTable(Year > 2010 & Year < 1920)) ' This is only reading the first column
```

.txt file looks like:

```
2009  -2  -3  3  5  7  8  10   9   7  4  3  5
2010  -1  -4  3  5  7  6   6   9  11  5  5  4
2011
...
...
2020
2021                                     ....
2022                                     ....
```

Comment: Do you have a sample `.txt` file that you can add to the question?

Comment: @MichaelTr7 please see edit

Comment: It seems like you are working with a matrix, rather than a [table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html). Are you looking for the column-wise [minimum command:](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) `min(TheTable, [], 1)`? This will return the minimum value for each column (including the years column.)

Comment: @minocha Iam looking to return a single minimum value after looking at those columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add column indexers `2:end` to get the columns after year. With the sample data, if we use `TheYear > 1920 & TheYear < 2011`, this is the output:

```matlab
MinimumValue = min(TheTable(TheYear > 1920 & TheYear < 2011, 2:end))

% MinimumValue =
%
%    -2    -4     3     5     7     6     6     9     7     4     3     4
```

To reduce to a single `min` value, use the ['all' flag](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html#d123e857103):

```matlab
MinimumValue = min(TheTable(TheYear < 2011 & TheYear > 1920, 2:end), [], 'all')

% MinimumValue =
%
%    -4
```

Comment: 's can this filter out further and return a single value for the minimum?

Comment: @Fil updated -- you can use `min( ... , [], 'all')`

Comment: This is only supported in version 2018b and above. If your version is older, then you can use double min: `min(min( ... ))`